# How to read multiple csv files in for loop using javascript

Tags: javascript

I am reading a csv file in javascript using the code:

```
import csv
  
file = open(r'C:\Users\hu170f\Documents\TEST1\MAAP-S12_LH_UP_PASS-LN1-V1.csv')
csvreader = csv.reader(file)
```

Now I have multiple files in the same directory and I need to read all the files present in the directory sequentially in a for loop. How to proceed with this.

Comment: Perhaps by reading the directory first.? Without knowing what the JavaScript platform being used is, what the `csv` ;package provides, and where `open` comes from it's  hard to go further. Please edit the question to provide more details of the  environment and show the code you've tried.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, install and require all the dependencies.
Example:

```
var fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const mysqlConnection = require('./connection');
const fastcsv = require('fast-csv');
```

Loop through each CSV file argument and run the formatFile function on
each

```
for (let i = 0; i < filePaths.length; i++) {
   formatFile(filePaths, i);
}
```